# java.sql.SQLException: No value especified for parameter 3 Java + Mysql

Tags: java, mysql, parameters, prepared-statement, batch-processing

I'm Brazilian and I'm trying to make a batch on database MySQL.

But the error

> "java.sql.SQLException: No value especified for parameter 3"

persists.

```
public ClienteCRUD(String nome, String cpf, String endereco, String cidade, String uf, String cep) throws SQLException {

        String[] str = {nome, cpf, endereco, cidade, uf, cep};

        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/vendas";
        String sql = "insert into cliente (id_cliente, nomeCliente, enderecoCliente, cidade, cep, uf, cpf) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?);";
        try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "root", "fabiio2");
        PreparedStatement stm = con.prepareStatement(sql)) {
            for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
                if (i == 0) {
                    stm.setInt(1, i + 4);
                    stm.setString(2, str[i]);
                }
                else {
                    stm.setString(i + 2, str[i]);
                }
                stm.addBatch();
            }
            stm.executeBatch();
    }

    }
```

My database contains seven columns, in which the first is auto-assigned.

Excuse me, but I'm new to Java.

I count on your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    public ClienteCRUD(String nome, String cpf, String endereco, String cidade, String uf, String cep) throws SQLException {
            String[] str = {nome, cpf, endereco, cidade, uf, cep};
            String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/vendas";
            String sql = "insert into cliente (id_cliente, nomeCliente, enderecoCliente, cidade, cep, uf, cpf) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
            try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "root", "fabiio2");
            PreparedStatement stm = con.prepareStatement(sql)) {

            //for a sql complete parameter
            for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
                if (i == 0) {
                     stm.setInt(1, i + 4);
                     stm.setString(2, str[i]);
                }
                else {
                     stm.setString(i + 2, str[i]);
                }
            }
            // to move this 
            stm.addBatch();
            stm.executeBatch();            
          }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked!
Can you explain why the "add.batch" is outside the "for"?
I thought that in each loop "for" have a "batch" instruction to assemble the whole process.
Once again, thank you!